# changing subset of 2D numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

Hello I am trying to do something that appeared simple at first but does not seems to work
I want to update a subset of a 2D numpy array

```
    import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[7,8,9,10,11],[10,2,-3,4,5],[7,8,9,10,11],[13,14,15,16,17]])
ind = [0,2]
print(A[ind][:,ind])
A[ind][:,ind] = A[ind][:,ind] + 3
print(A[ind][:,ind])
#
# try another way
#
B = np.array([[3,3],[3,3]])
A[ind][:,ind] = A[ind][:,ind] + B
print(A[ind][:,ind])
#
# try a very stupid way
#
n = len(ind)
for i in range(0,n):
    i1 = ind[i]
    for j in range(0,n):
        j1 = ind[j]
        A[i1][j1] = A[i1][j1] + 3
print(A[ind][:,ind])
# now it's work ?????
```

Comment: What is your mean by "does not seems to work". What happened to it? Please share more details.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned: don't chain indexes when performing assignment. It may or may not work.

Try with:

```
x,y = np.meshgrid(ind,ind)

A[x,y] +=3
```

Output:

```
array([[ 4,  2,  6,  4,  5],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [13,  2,  0,  4,  5],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but I do not quite understand why...

Answer (score 0):

```
In [28]: A=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[7,8,9,10,11],[10,2,-3,4,5],[7,8,9,10,11],[13,14,15,16,17]])
In [29]: ind=[0,2]
```

Look at what you double indexing selects:

```
In [30]: A[ind][:,ind]
Out[30]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [10, -3]])
```

We can do the same with one indexing step.  `ix_` helps:

```
In [31]: inds = np.ix_(ind,ind)
In [32]: inds
Out[32]: 
(array([[0],
        [2]]),
 array([[0, 2]]))
In [34]: A[inds]
Out[34]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [10, -3]])
```

Now we can modify that block of elements:

```
In [35]: A[inds] += 3
In [36]: A
Out[36]: 
array([[ 4,  2,  6,  4,  5],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [13,  2,  0,  4,  5],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])
In [37]: A[inds]
Out[37]: 
array([[ 4,  6],
       [13,  0]])
```

Other equivalent indexings (same arrays as in the `inds` tuple)

```
In [38]: A[[[0],[2]], [0,2]]
Out[38]: 
array([[ 4,  6],
       [13,  0]])
In [39]: ind=np.array(ind)
In [40]: A[ind[:,None], ind]
Out[40]: 
array([[ 4,  6],
       [13,  0]])
```

When you use the chained indexing, the first one makes a copy:

```
In [41]: A[ind]
Out[41]: 
array([[ 4,  2,  6,  4,  5],
       [13,  2,  0,  4,  5]])
In [42]: _[:,ind]
Out[42]: 
array([[ 4,  6],
       [13,  0]])
```